# Binding a Dictionary<string, string> to a DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, dictionary, datalist

I have a Dictionary (let's call it info) that I am trying to bind to a DataList (we'll call it directory). The dictionary is declared as follows:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> info = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
       {"AdvertisementID", "1"},
       {"CompanyName", "Test"},
       //More elements
      };
```

Now, I bind the Dictionary to the DataList as follows:

```
    directory.DataSource = info;
    directory.DataBind();
```

My asp code looks like this:

```
    <asp:DataList ID = "directory" runat="server" RepeatColums="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" DataKeyField="Key">
    <ItemTemplate>
            //HTML Formatting
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CompanyName") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

For whatever reason, "CompanyName" cannot be found. When outputting Container.DataItem.ToString(), all that appears is AdvertisementID (the first thing in the dictionary). What am I doing incorrectly?

**EDIT:** I want to also mention that I've attempted implementing this solution to no avail:
    [Binding DataList to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645074/binding-datalist-to-dictionary)

**EDIT 2:** What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

I have a bunch of information that I pulled from a database in a Dictionary. This dictionary is set up like Dictionary, both as strings. And I am trying to output this info to a webpage.

**EDIT 3**
Using the solution below (Binding a list of objects instead of a dictionary), my asp code still cannot find the property "CompanyName". The object and all of the Strings within it appear in the DataItem in the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the Dictionary like that. Items on dictionary are `KeyValuePair` and only available properties are `Key` and `Value`.

So, the only 2 valid options would be

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Key") %>
```

Or

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>
```

You may want to explain better what you're trying to achieve since it's possible that this is not enough for solving your problem.

**EDIT**

You would normally have something like tis

```
public class Info
{
    public int AdvertisementID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    //More elements
}
```

And then

```
IList<Info> infoList = GetList();
directory.DataSource = infoList;
directory.DataBind();
```

You can keep your html as it is if you implement something like this

Comment: I have a bunch of information that I pulled from a database in a Dictionary. This dictionary is set up like Dictionary<columnName, value>, both as strings. And I am trying to output this info to a webpage.

Comment: @cruskai239: can't you define a class for it instead of using a dictionary?

Comment: If I were to define a class, how would I attach it to the DataBinder?

Comment: To clarify, GetList() just means the list of Info objects. Therefore, IList<Info> infoList = new List<Info>(); is acceptable as long as stuff is added afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Key` and `Value` instead.

(`Value` instead of CompanyName)

Comment: If my understanding is correct, then I need to use

        DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value");

But where do I determine which key it pulls from?

Comment: @cruskai239 You don't; it does it *for each key*.